# Python subprocess using perl for formatting is giving incomplete output

Tags: python, bash, perl, subprocess, python-3.8

I'm having an issue reading output from a python subprocess command.

The bash command from whose output I want to read:

```
pacmd list-sink-inputs | tr '\n' '\r' | perl -pe 's/ *index: ([0-9]+).+?application\.process\.id = "([^\r]+)"\r.+?(?=index:|$)/\2:\1\r/g' | tr '\r' '\n'
```

When I run this via bash I get the intended output:

```
4 sink input(s) available.
6249:72
20341:84
20344:86
20350:87
```

When I try to get it's output via python's subprocess running either one :

1. `subprocess.Popen(cmnd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0].decode('UTF-8')`
2. `check_output(cmnd,shell=True).decode('UTF-8')`
3. `subprocess.run(cmnd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.decode('utf-8')`

where `cmnd = """pacmd list-sink-inputs | tr '\n' '\r' | perl -pe 's/ *index: ([0-9]+).+?application\.process\.id = "([^\r]+)"\r.+?(?=index:|$)/\2:\1\r/g' | tr '\r' '\n'"""`

It gives the following output:

`'4 sink input(s) available.\n\x02:\x01\n\x02:\x01\n\x02:\x01\n\x02:\x01\n'`

Which is unintended as it doesn't have the 6249:72 ,etc. numbers I want. Even stderr is blank and returncode is 0 as intended.

The only workaround, I could find was to redirect the bash output to a text file and then read the text file via python which I don't want to use because that's unnecessary file IO.

I've already gone through [Missing output from subprocess command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6610503/missing-output-from-subprocess-command), [Python Subprocess Grep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7956865/python-subprocess-grep), [Python subprocess run() is giving abnormal output [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65965244/python-subprocess-run-is-giving-abnormal-output) and many others but can't wrap my head around what's going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a quoting issue. `"""\1"""` means `chr(0o1)`. To produce the string `\1`, you could use `"""\\1"""`. The other instances of `\` should be `\\` as well.

Since all instances of `\` need to be escaped, you could also use `r"""\1"""`.

Other issues:

- `\1` and `\2` outside of a regular expression is wrong anyways. You should be using `$1` and `$2`.
- There's no use for a mutliline literal here. `"..."` or `r"..."` would suffice.
- The whole `tr` business can be avoided by using `-0777` to cause `perl` to treat the entire file as one line.

This gives us:

`cmnd = "pacmd list-sink-inputs | perl -0777pe's/ *index: (\\d+).+?application\\.process\\.id = "([^\\n]+)"\\n.+?(?=index:|$)/$2:$1\\n/sag'"`

or

`cmnd = r"pacmd list-sink-inputs | perl -0777pe's/ *index: (\d+).+?application\.process\.id = "([^\n]+)"\n.+?(?=index:|$)/$2:$1\n/sag'"`

But why is Perl being used at all here? You could easily do the same thing in Python!

Comment: ohh, got the issue, Thanks a lot. Your answer works after using triple quotes: `cmnd = r"""bash-command""" `worked. As to why I'm using Perl within the bash command and not processing the output in Python, [Perl is way faster than Python for text processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12793562/text-processing-python-vs-perl-performance). I tried but coudn't upvote your answer because of the min. 15 rep limit.